# Getting SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL for an incoming DTLS Connection on an existing DTLS Connection on the same port

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, dtls

On an existing DTLS connection i.e. DTLS handshake already done successfully on port 5000 if server gets an incoming DTLS Connection i.e. DTLS Client Hello packet then SSL_read is generating `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`.

Can anyone give me a clue as to why.

Scenario is that Client had established a DTLS connection with server on port 5000 of server. IP address of client changes may be due to transition from Wi-Fi to 3G or vice-versa. So, now Client will again try to establish DTLS connection with server on same port 5000 of server.

Please anyone let me know as to

- Q1. why SSL_read is generating the error SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL and what can be done to proceed ?
- Q2. Whether we can handle another incoming DTLS connection on an existing DTLS Connection on the same port without cleaning-up the already existing DTLS connection ?

Thanks in advance for the help,
Vineet Srivastava

Comment: Your question is flying under the radar. Always indicate your programming environment. I presume this is about code you have, right? If so, where's the code? If this is just about OpenSSL itself you might try serverfault or superuser instead.

Comment: Programming environment - Unix.

Comment: Have found the solution for the problem. Problems identified were two: 1. On getting an incoming DTLS connection on the port having another DLTS Connection it was required to generate another SSL Handle and treat it as seperate DTLS Connection. 2. length provided in SSL_Read call has to be proper.  After giving proper parameter and generating a new SSL Handle the problem was solved. Thanks anyways for comments.

Answer (score 1):

Have found the solution for the problem.

Problems identified were two:

1. On getting an incoming DTLS connection on the port having another DLTS Connection it was required to generate another SSL Handle and treat it as seperate DTLS Connection.
2. length provided in SSL_Read call has to be proper.

After giving proper parameter and generating a new SSL Handle the problem was solved. Thanks anyways for comments.